# Failed to install ocaml on windows

Tags: windows, cygwin, ocaml, opam

I'm tring to install OCaml on windows 10, following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39693955/6264263). When I run `opam install depext` command on Cygwin, I got an error:

> The compilation of opam-depext failed at "C:\OCaml64\bin\make.exe".
>
> context     2.0.0 | win32/x86_64 |  | git+https://github.com/fdopen/opam-> > > > repository-mingw.git#opam2
>
> path        ~/.opam/4.07.1+msvc64c/.opam-switch/build/opam-depext.1.1.2
>
> command     C:\OCaml64\bin\make.exe
>
> exit-code   2
>
> env-file    ~/.opam/log/opam-depext-9756-5f1023.env
>
> output-file ~/.opam/log/opam-depext-9756-5f1023.out
>
> operable program or batch file.
>
> File "cmdliner/src/cmdliner.ml", line 1:
>
> Error: Assembler error, input left in file C:\OCaml64\tmp\camlasme17f85.asm
>
> ERROR while compiling opam-depext.1.1.2
>
> <><> Error report <><><>
>
> +- The following actions failed
>
> | - build opam-depext 1.1.2
>
> +-
>
> - No changes have been performed

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CTu7.png)

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: do not put screenshot, copy and past the test. In addition you need to put how you arrive there. I do not see the relevance for cygwin as cygwin has its ocalm package

Comment: I just run the command `opam install depext` in cygwin, then I got there.

Comment: Seems like a tool run attempt failed because the tool wasn't found. Possibly a path (that contain *SPACE*s) quote problem. Check any existing output / log files.

Comment: Hi, @matzeri, I just edited my post, add more error information. Can you help me?

Comment: Hi, @CristiFati. Maybe there is some space in my path, but I couldn't find it out. I installed it on C:\ocaml. And I posted more information about the error, can you help me to figure it out?

Comment: As your Ocalm is not the Cygwin one, running it from cygwin is likely confusing it or Opam

Comment: Where is your *mingw* installed? Or what build toolchain are you using?